# If API results changed, print updated information

Tags: javascript, discord

I am trying to build out a simple Discord bot in JS.  The logic behind the bot is that it makes a call out to the Udemy API and grabs the student questions.  The student questions returns a total count.  I'm looking to have my Discord bot print out a message to chat any time the question count changes.  Here is my code so far:

```
let checkUdemy = async () => {
    let getUdemy = async () => {
        let token = "xxxxxxxx";
        let response = await axios.get(
            "https://udemy.com/instructor-api/v1/taught-courses/questions/?page_size=1", {
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
                }
            }
        );
        let qa = response.data;
        return qa;
    };
    let qaValue = await getUdemy()
    let count = qaValue.count;
};

checkUdemy();
var timerID = setInterval(checkUdemy, 60000);
```

Currently, the bot checks the API every minute.  I can store the value of count inside of the function, but obviously that does me no good currently.  Basically, I'm looking to store the value of count as a variable and if it changes, then the bot will print the qaValue.message.  I'm stuck on the logic here.

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I may be completely misunderstanding the question, but I think what you are looking for is storing the count outside the function as a global variable perhaps. Everytime a new count is received this could then be checked against the new count, and set the global variable to the new count. Feel free to clarify, as I am a little bit confused by what the problem seems to be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store previous count value so that you can compare previous and new value, if both are different you need to update/print the message.

```
let previousCount = 0;
let checkUdemy = async () => {
    let getUdemy = async () => {
        let token = "xxxxxxxx";
        let response = await axios.get(
            "https://udemy.com/instructor-api/v1/taught-courses/questions/?page_size=1", {
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
                }
            }
        );
        let qa = response.data;
        return qa;
    };
    let qaValue = await getUdemy()
    let count = qaValue.count;
    // check if count and previousCount are different
    if(previousCount!==count){

      printMessage(count);
      previousCount=count;
    }
};


function printMessage(count){
  console.log(count)
}

checkUdemy();
var timerID = setInterval(checkUdemy, 60000);
```